# UTF-8 decoder fails on non-ASCII characters

Tags: c

Note: if you've followed my recent questions, you'll see that they're all about my Unicode library exercise in C -- as one of my first few serious projects in C, I'm having many problems, so I'm sorry if I'm asking too many questions about one thing.

Part of my library decodes UTF-8 encoded `char` pointers into raw `unsigned` code points. However, certain planes don't decode correctly. Let's take a look at the (relevant) code:

```
typedef struct string {
 unsigned long length;
 unsigned *data;
} string;

// really simple stuff

string *upush(string *s, unsigned c) {
 if (!s->length) s->data = (unsigned *) malloc((s->length = 1) * sizeof(unsigned));
 else   s->data = (unsigned *) realloc(s->data, ++s->length * sizeof(unsigned));
 s->data[s->length - 1] = c;
 return s;
}

// UTF-8 conversions

string ctou(char *old) {
 unsigned long i, byte = 0, cur = 0;
 string new;
 new.length = 0;
 for (i = 0; old[i]; i++)
  if (old[i] < 0x80) upush(&new, old[i]);
  else if (old[i] < 0xc0)
   if (!byte) {
    byte = cur = 0;
    continue;
   } else {
    cur |= (unsigned)(old[i] & 0x3f) << (6 * (--byte));
    if (!byte) upush(&new, cur), cur = 0;
   }
  else if (old[i] < 0xc2) continue;
  else if (old[i] < 0xe0) {
   cur = (unsigned)(old[i] & 0x1f) << 6;
   byte = 1;
  }
  else if (old[i] < 0xf0) {
   cur = (unsigned)(old[i] & 0xf) << 12;
   byte = 2;
  }
  else if (old[i] < 0xf5) {
   cur = (unsigned)(old[i] & 0x7) << 18;
   byte = 3;
  }
  else continue;
 return new;
}
```

All `upush` does, by the way, is pushes a code point onto the end of a `string`, reallocating memory as needed. `ctou` does the decoding work, and stores the number of bytes still needed in a sequence in `byte`, as well as the in-progress code point in `cur`.

The code all seems correct to me. Let's try decoding `U+10ffff`, which is `f4 8f bf bd` in UTF-8. Doing this:

```
long i;
string b = ctou("\xf4\x8f\xbf\xbd");
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
 printf("%z ", b.data[i]);
```

should print out:

```
10ffff
```

but instead it prints out:

```
fffffff4 ffffff8f ffffffbf ffffffbd
```

which is basically the four bytes of UTF-8, with `ffffff` tacked on before it.

Any guidance as to what is wrong in my code?

Comment: By the way, your question subject is misleading. The problem has nothing to do with high plane (non-BMP) chracters; it happens with **any** non-ascii chracter. It also really has nothing to do with UTF-8, but rather with basic C arithmetic. You do have a few bugs in your UTF-8 decoder too, the worst of which is that you will decode invalid overlong sequences.

Comment: I've edited the title to improve the relevancy. I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know some of the other bugs you've spotted.

Comment: You're blocking the two-byte overlongs, but not longer overlongs eg. 0xE0,0x80,0xBC. You're also allowing codepoints over 0x10FFFF, surrogate code units (should not appear in UTF-8), and sequences of >=0xC0 byte followed by low-byte(s) followed by 0x80-0xBF byte. A `while` loop with distinct code/checking for each length-case might be easier. But really I'd use some existing library code to decode UTF-8 rather than rolling it yourself (as mis-decoded/invalid sequences can end up allowing filter evasion with security consequences). Also the `upush` implementation is pathologically inefficient.

Comment: Wow, my code is a *really* crappy implementation! ;) -- I'd better get to work on these. However, on the subject of `upush`, if `upush` works with one code point only in itself, how can I improve efficiency? It does all it needs to do; `realloc` then stick it in. Also, I would use another library; I'm just writing this as an exercise for my developing C skills.

Comment: Part of why this code bothers me is that pathetically slow UTF-8 implementations were and still continue to be a big obstacle to Unicode adoption. The first release of GNU `grep` with UTF-8 support became over a hundred times slower, even when it was only processing ASCII characters, as soon as you set a UTF-8 locale. If you're going to write UTF-8 code, do it right. Otherwise, use existing code that does it right.

Comment: Other then the fact that I `realloc` every character is pushed, instead of allocating double and then shrinking, what else makes it 'pathetically slow'?

Comment: Aside from `upush`, the code as you have it is fairly fast... but it's easy to be fast when your implementation is wrong. :-) Think about how to make it fast once you fix the decoding of "overlong sequences" and surrogate codepoints. Also keep in mind that any UTF-8 decoder will be slow if it incurs lots of overhead per-character. High-performance code will operate on strings, but will also avoid setup and exit overhead in case it needs to be called on short strings/single characters.

Comment: A question about error handling; Unicode says that you shouldn't accept surrogates/overlongs, but doesn't say if you should ignore, warn, or throw an exception. The latter, done by Python 3, is probably not good because it prevents error fixing. Currently, I ignore everything silently. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The char type is allowed to be signed, and conversion to int and then unsigned (which is what happens implicitly when you convert directly to unsigned) shows the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char c = '\xF4';
  int i = c;
  unsigned n = i;
  printf("%X\n", n);
  n = c;
  printf("%X\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

Prints:

> FFFFFFF4
>   FFFFFFF4

Use unsigned char instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! Changing the prototype of `ctou` to this fixed it: `string ctou(unsigned char *old);`

Answer (score 2):

You've probably ignored the fact that `char` is a signed type on your platform. Always use:

- `unsigned char` if you will be reading the actual values of bytes
- `signed char` if you're using bytes as small signed integers
- `char` for abstract strings where you don't care about the values except perhaps for 0.

By the way, your code is extremely inefficient. Instead of calling `realloc` over and over per-character, why not allocate `sizeof(unsigned)*(strlen(old)+1)` to begin with, then reduce the size at the end if it's too big? Of course this is only one of the many inefficiencies.